# Security Concerns in mobile apps

Tags: security, mobile

I've have a project coming up for which I am currently evaluating the approach (Native vs Hybrid using PhoneGap). With respect to this evaluation process (lots of googling mostly), I'm clear on most points, except one. Security.

A lot of articles I read said that Hybrid apps are less secure compared to native apps, but did not elaborate much on the details. I want to understand, exactly how is it less secure.

Only 1 article dived a little more than skin deep on this topic saying the security risks can be:

- App Source Code
- Data at rest
- Data in transit
- URL security issues

I want to understand this topic in a little greater detail. Can anybody elaborate a little on it or point me to some helpful resources?

P.S.: I know this is a non-focused / open-ended question, but I'm really stuck on this one and I've been through a lot of googling already. Moderators, please don't close this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purely speculation (speaking from experience here on both native, hybrid on iOS and Android), but Hybrid apps require data to be more accessible by tying it to APIs and storing with common data formats. This implicitly allows more attack vectors because you are making the data inherently more accessible by hybridizing it. As a native application, the app and associated data must be stored in a proprietary format. This means that an attacker or malware must specifically be built to address data access in that format, whereas with a hybrid app, the malware or attacker may access the data via the common APIs or in the common data storage format.

Also, anytime you are interacting "over the wire" with a server, native apps use low-level communication, opening a socket connection, whereas with hybrid apps, the data is encapsulated (usually) on top of HTTP. This means that an attacker has fewer obstacles to overcome if all they are doing is sniffing traffic on port 80 (versus sniffing like port 2030 in some bizarre protocol). One of the most common ways to interact with a server using "hybrid" communications (usually over HTTP again) is via URL. This means things like username and password will be contained in the URL being sent in cleartext (as a stupid, stupid example): `http://www.example.com/control_me?username=foo&password=bar`.

As for the app source code, this goes back to accessibility. Hybrid app source code needs to be open, by definition. It needs to run on multiple platforms and here in app land we usually mean HTML5 when we talk about hybrid app source code. That means your entire methodology can be downloaded and reverse engineered (or just opened and looked at), because you need to send the source in order for it to run on the device. This is versus a native app, which is basically compiled java or objective-c, and hard or impossible to "decompile".

Comment: In the source code section, when you say "need to send the source", do you mean download the entire HTML, CSS & JS? I thought in case of hybrid apps, this source was bundled with the app itself. Also, if my native app uses standard protocols like SOAP, HTTP etc, is it equally vulnerable as hybrid app?

Comment: To address your first issue, that's exactly what I mean: It's "bundled" in order to run, and therefore every client downloads your source when they download your app. Second, yes, that's exactly right, and one of the reasons why the "data in transit" point is not particularly an amazing revelation. If it's sensitive, it is generally your civic duty to encrypt it.